# Mensajes según contexto en ErrorViewer

Tags: genexus

Según veo, los mensajes desplegados por Genexus tienen la clase "gx-warning-message" o "gx-error-message" según si es mediante la una regla error o el comando msg.

Ya que a veces cuando trabajamos en Webpanels, queremos mostrar errores o warnings, ¿Hay alguna forma de elegir el modo en que queremos desplegar un mensaje?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Daniel, supongo has probado de cambiar la clase del error-viewer dinámicamente y no funcionó; he leido en algún foro que eso parece que no ha dado resultado.

En virtud de ello, una idea podría ser intentar cambiar la clase del DIV dinámicamente mediante jquery.-

Comment: El problema no es el diseño general del error viewer, sino diferenciar entre warnings y errores desde Genexus. Genexus ya lo hace internamente y la diferencia es la regla error y errores internos y el comando msg

Comment: Daniel, quizás no trasmití la idea correctamente. 

Me refiero a cambios dinámicos (en tiempo de ejecución). 

Te dejo aquí una referencia de como mediante inline styles (que habría que embeberlos en el código genexus) y aplicando un poco de teoría de CSS mas alguna función JS es posible lograr el efecto deseado.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049436/how-to-override-inline-style-dynamically

De esa forma es tu aplicación la que toma el control y la solución aplica tanto a regla error como así también a comando msg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel,

No, no es posible mostrar un mensaje de Error (programáticamente) desde un WebPanel.

Solamente se permite usar el Comando "msg" y no el "error".

Para posibilitar este escenario, o bien puedes crearte un UserControl o usar uno [ya existente](http://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?bootstrapalert,en)

Comment: Gracias!, sería bueno algo como agregarle un parámetro al comando "msg" que identifique el nivel de error.

Comment: Si, de acuerdo. La diferencia es que en una TRN detiene la ejecución. Mientras que en un WebPanel no detendría la misma.